# Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement in Android?

Tags: android, error-handling, android-tabhost

Am very new to Android projects. Just i tried to work with `TabHost` controller in Android. I have got a code from this link, [coderzheaven.com](http://coderzheaven.com/2011/05/android-tabbars-example/). But, in this code i received one error `Syntax error, insert ";" to complete`. Here is my code,

```
package tab.fragment;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

    public class TabBarSample extends TabActivity 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

            TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_id1");
            TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_id2");
            TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_id3");

            firstTabSpec.setIndicator("Time").setContent(new Intent(this,Time.class));
            secondTabSpec.setIndicator("Date").setContent(new Intent(this,Date.class));
            thirdTabSpec.setIndicator("Option").setContent(new Intent(this,Option.class));

            tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
            tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);
            tabHost.addTab(thirdTabSpec); //Here the error occuring..
        }
    }
```

How can i do this? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no syntax error in the code you posted. The error is most likely a consequence of bad syntax above those lines.

Comment: @Mat Thanks. Here i edited and posted the entire code for the reference. Please help me.

Comment: Is that your complete file? There is still no syntax error in what you posted.

Comment: there is no error as such try to clean your project and run

Comment: Post the rest of the file, specifically the package and import stuff.

Comment: Here i have added more code from the project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely it is not in fact the `;` causing the problem, but a missing closing `}`

Comment: Thanks. Here i edited and posted the entire code for the reference. Please help me to find out the solution. Thanks.

Comment: We would need to see more: Like, what are you importing? There must be more to the file as that chunk provided doesn't contain the error. It, still, is most likely a missing closing `}` Have you tried adding that at the end of the Clause, or even towards the end of the file?

Comment: thanks for the response. I have edited my question and posted the whole codes. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get any error. Maybe simply try cleaning your project if you haven't already: Project --> Clean --> Clean All or Select the one. That possibly may be your problem, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

You might be seeing this if you are directly coping pasting code from web pages/pdf's. The hidden characters are not seen in eclipse IDE. One can paste it in a textpad before putting it in IDE.